# Shape does not get face created

Tags: 3d, sketchup

I am very new to sketchup and trying to do something simple. A shape like so:

[image]

I started with two arc lines and then used the 'lines' tool to connect the bases. I was hoping a face would be created that I could pull upward, but it wasn't.

How can I create a face for the top of this structure?

Another angle, it's like the frame for swings on a playground

[image]

Comment: Is this shape in a plane or is it already 3-dimensional?

Comment: @user287001 it's three dimensional ... will include another angle momentarily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have none planar closed curves. If you had one, then you also would have an already existing face that you could pull to create a volume. All 3D volumes in SketchUP are between planar faces. No curved surfaces exist altough some surfaces can appear to be curved due the high number of planar faces and smoothed rendering. The planar curve must be drawn on a plane. If you collect a bunch of 3D curves that happen to be in a plane when moved together, they probably are not considered planar so no pullable face appears.

If you want something like this, it must be pulled horizontally:

[image]